# How to SSH to a VirtualBox guest externally through a host?

Tags: ssh, virtualbox

I have a Ubuntu VM running on my Windows 7 machine. How do I set it up so that I can access the webserver externally through SSH?

I found steps (*[Setup SSH access between VirtualBox Host and Guest VMs](http://www.wiredrevolution.com/virtualbox/setup-ssh-access-between-virtualbox-host-and-guest-vms)*) to be able to ssh to my guest from my host, but that still leaves me with the problem of accessing it through my router.

I suppose that I could install an SSH server on my Windows machine and then tunnel a few times (though I'm not 100% sure what to use in terms of local, dynamic, etc. or how to set up multiple tunnels?), but is there a way to make the VM directly accessible to my router so I could directly port forward to it?

Comment: There's a much easier way to do this, using Vagrant (which creates ready-to-go VMs (ssh-accessable, ip-accessable) from a config file or GUI). I don't know your use-case, but I've written a large tutorial on [How to create an ssh-accessable Ubuntu server VM with Vagrant](http://www.dev-metal.com/setup-virtual-machine-multiple-vagrant-puphpet/), useful when you want to setup a LAMP-based development machine.

Comment: Vagrant is a great tool, but it isn't compatible with the more recent versions of virtualbox

Comment: Best answer is further down:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10410527/2214806

Comment: You can check this tutorial http://wiki.workassis.com/virtualbox-ssh-between-host-and-guest/

Comment: Is think could be usefull to have a new, specifi, place where to speak about virtualization
https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28201/proposal-for-a-site-about-virtualization

Answer (score 1357, accepted):

The best way to login to a guest Linux VirtualBox VM is [port forwarding](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward). By default, you should have one interface already which is using [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation). Then go to the *Network* settings and click the *Port Forwarding* button.  Add a new *Rule*. As the rule name, insert "ssh". As "Host port", insert 3022. As "Guest port", insert 22. Everything else of the rule can be left blank.

or from the command line

```bash
VBoxManage modifyvm myserver --natpf1 "ssh,tcp,,3022,,22"
```

where 'myserver' is the name of the created VM. Check the added rules:

```bash
VBoxManage showvminfo myserver | grep 'Rule'
```

That's all! Please be sure you don't forget to install an [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) server in the VM:

```bash
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

To SSH into the guest VM, write:

```bash
ssh -p 3022 user@127.0.0.1
```

Where `user` is your username within the VM.

Comment: What do I use as a host name or IP address?

Comment: Keyslinger, just left blank, you don't need fill them

Comment: Note that you need to enable VirtualBox firewall access for both public and private networks.

Comment: @Keyslinger, is this what you were looking for?  `ssh -p 3022 user@127.0.0.1`  That was the one step that I was missing and just went to find on another site.

Comment: just want to give props to you guys. THis answer helped me with my own problems with the vm. which i now convert into my own solution at superuser http://superuser.com/a/527462/8184

Comment: This helped me get a bit further but still having issues.  If anyone could look at my issue here http://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/5399/4556 it would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: I also added the port redirect from 2020 to 80, so I can easily access Apache from the browser using http://192.0.0.1:2020. VBoxManage modifyvm myserver --natpf1 "ssh,tcp,,2020,,80"

Comment: @AngeloR. first see if your guestVM can ssh into itself. I'm setting up a minimal dev environment, and as it turns out, minimal can mean not even an SSH server.

Comment: I did this, restarted the VM, captured the IP address of the VM using `ifconfig`, tried `ssh <GUEST_IP>`, still couldn't connect

Comment: However, when I moved the Network Adapter to the `Bridged` mode, it worked.

Comment: See VirtualBox networking docs: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_nat

Comment: Works great with ssh -p 3022 user@127.0.0.1, but how can I connect from another machine somewhere in the internet to my vbox via windows? I used the IP-address of windows and tried ssh -p 3022 user@mywindowsip, but got a connection timeout. If I use the same command on my host machine, it works.

Comment: Thanks! Works great with the Cloudera Quickstart VM, too.

Comment: This worked for me, with guest OS SUSE 9.3  However I did have to modify the guest-OS firewall to allow SSH service  (or, just disable the guest-OS firewall).  These firewall changes are made using whatever firewall config tool the guest-OS provides (eg, YAST).

Comment: Make sure you're not using `sudo VBoxManage` since it won't be your current user and make sure that the vm is stopped ;)

Comment: I used this along with starting the VM in headless mode:

VBoxManage startvm "vmname" --type headless

Comment: thebigdog, you can headless directly:

VBoxHeadless -s 'vmname'

Comment: How can I add the box's ip into the `/etc/hosts` file to create a link alias ?

Comment: It should be "localhost" anyway. Otherwise add a line with "127.0.0.1 localhost" or similar.

Comment: This works. However, the problems are: 1. The connection is extremely slow. It takes a few seconds for the "enter password" prompt to show up. 2. The password is not buffered, i.e., you have to enter the password of the ssh key each time you ssh to the VM.

Comment: I've figured out the reason for not being able to buffer the ssh password. That was because I didn't add the public key to my VM. However, the login is still extremely slow and takes at least five seconds.

Comment: Why are we using port 3022 and not the default 22?

Comment: The comments weren't that clear - I logged into the guest OS (Ubuntu 14.04 in my case) and ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`. After that I ran the VM headless on my Mac and was able to ssh in :)

Comment: @York I use an `expect` script to automate an SSH session, including the password input.

Comment: The ssh is not connecting saying Connection closed by 10.0.2.15

Comment: Just as a helpful tip to list all virtual machines before you start this task, use `VBoxManage list vms`

Comment: To make life easier, open ~/.ssh/config, add the following `Host mybox HostName 127.0.0.1 User myuser Port 3022` to that file (add indent yourself), then you only need to `ssh mybox` each time :)

Comment: If you do `route -n` in your linux VM, you'll find the IP to ssh into on the `default` line. On my windows it is: 10.0.2.2. (When adapter is NAT and with the port forwarding as above.)

Comment: I prefer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10410527/4200039 as it avoids messing around with port forwarding.

Comment: damn, tnx... I tried everything then simple port fordwarding works

Comment: @Seraphim, we are using Port `3022` because possibly the machine hosting the VM may already have an SSH daemon listening on port `22`. This extends the answer beyond Windows machines running VirtualBox, e.g. to a linux host environment. Point here is a) one port per service (can't listen on `22` if a service already uses it) and b) we need to use a non-privileged port [higher than `1024`](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-open-ports/).

Comment: I found this to be of enormous help for me to access a VM that did not allow to login graphically any more but that had an SSH server  installed. Many thanks!

Comment: Ok with that, buy how can you ssh into your guest os via an external network..... I mean using PUBLIC IP ADDRESS !!

Comment: This is the most voted solution but it didn't work for me. VirtualBox 6.1 running on OSX Mountain Lion. Ubuntu Server 20.04 running as VM. I set up port forwarding as instructed, but when I try to ssh into the VM, it times out. Yes, sshd is running on the VM.

Comment: Very useful! I am wondering why `-p 3022` works, but if I try to append `:3022` to the hostname it says "Name or service not known"

Answer (score 131):

Change the adapter type in VirtualBox to bridged, and set the guest to use [DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) or set a static [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) outside of the bounds of DHCP. This will cause the Virtual Machine to act like a normal guest on your home network. You can then port forward.

Comment: Any Idea how 2 adapter configuration will work? One on NAT and other on Host Only?

Comment: In my opinion exposing the VM on the local network is not the best option (for instance in an office network), the solution proposed by @vkostromin keeps the encapsulation of the VM within the host.

Comment: @VictorP. can you please explain why it's not the best option in an office network?  Is it due to security or?

Comment: Even knowing that is not the best option, in my current configuration  set the adapter to bridged is the only solution that works.

Answer (score 71):

Keeping the NAT adapter and adding a second host-only adapter works amazing, and is crucial for laptops (where the external network always changes).

http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2010/02/08/howto-ssh-into-virtualbox-3-linux-guests/

Remember to create a host-only network in virtualbox itself (GUI -> settings -> network), otherwise you can't create the host-only interface on the guest.

Comment: Only this answer worked for me, nothing else did. Also, I just added  additional adapter and it worked, didn't need to edit the `/etc/network/interfaces`, Thanks!

Comment: Agreed this is the best answer.  Otherwise, you're jumping through hoops every time you want to access a common service (`ssh`, `sftp`, etc.) since you'd have to go through a non-standard port.

Comment: I prefer to link to Internet Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20160523035053/https://muffinresearch.co.uk/howto-ssh-into-virtualbox-3-linux-guests/ - https://web.archive.org/web/20170701174835/http://christophermaier.name/2010/09/01/host-only-networking-with-virtualbox/ is another good explanation.

Comment: another good source on setting this up https://2buntu.com/articles/1513/accessing-your-virtualbox-guest-from-your-host-os/

Comment: ping from the host to the guest works but ssh returns `port 22: Connection refused`.

Comment: @Sparkler is sshd running? Is there a firewall closing ports?

Comment: Note that if the host-only adapter name (should be vboxnet0) is not shown, you have to create it first via: File – Host Network Manager – Create – [use defaults].

Answer (score 27):

You can also use a **Bridged Network** (or "Bridge Adapter", in newer versions) in **network settings**. This will put your VM in a VLAN with your machine. So you can just ssh into the VM like this.

> ssh user@IP_OF_VM

Comment: With this solution does the SSH connection go across the LAN?

Answer (score 24):

## How to do host-only network ([better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10410527) than bridged) for Solaris 10 and Ubuntu 16.04

### Add Host-only interface

1. Virtualbox > File > Preferences > Network > Host-only Networks > Add
2. Shutdown vm.
3. VM's Settings > Network. First adapter should be Nat, second Host-only.
4. Start cmd.exe and run `ipconfig /all`. You should see lines:

   ```
   Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:
      ...
      IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.59.1
   ```

   Second adapter in guest should also be in 192.168.59.*.
5. Start VM.

### Solaris 10

1. Check [settings](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-4554/esxhc/index.html) `ifconfig -a`. You should see e1000g0 and e1000g1. We are interested in e1000g1.
2. `ifconfig e1000g down`
3. `ifconfig e1000g 192.168.56.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`
4. Check from host if this interface is reachable: `ping 192.168.56.10`

#### Preserve those settings upon reboot

```
# vi /etc/hostname.e1000g1
192.168.56.10 netmask 255.255.255.0
# reboot
```

#### [Configure ssh](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2426/gksja.html) service ([administering](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/intro-smf-basics-s11-1729181.html)) to login as root (not adviced)

Check if ssh is enabled

```
# svcs -a | grep ssh
online         15:29:57 svc:/network/ssh:default
```

Modify /etc/ssh/sshd_config so there is

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Restart ssh service

```
svcadm restart ssh
```

From host check it

```
ssh root@192.168.56.10
```

## Ubuntu 16.04

List interfaces:

```
ip addr
```

You should see three interfaces like lo, enp0s3, enp0s8. We will use the third.

Edit /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet static
    address 192.168.56.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Then `sudo ifup enp0s8`. Check if enp0s8 got correct address. You should see your ip:

```
 $ ip addr show enp0s8
 ...
    inet 192.168.56.10/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global secondary enp0s8
```

If not, you may run `sudo ifdown enp0s8 && sudo ifup enp0s8`

https://superuser.com/questions/424083/virtualbox-host-ssh-to-guest/424115#424115

Comment: This doesn't work if your host-only network is on `192.168.59.1` and you specify `192.168.56.10` for the static guest IP. The entire class C subnet address must match exactly, so you would have to use something like `192.168.59.10` inside the guest instead.

Answer (score 19):

In order to ssh to a Ubuntu VM running in VirtualBox from your host machine, you need to set up two network adapters for the VM.

First of all, stop the VM if not yet.

Then select the VM and click the Settings menu in the VirtualBox toolbar:

[image]

## Set up Adapter 1

[image]

## Set up Adapter 2

[image]

(Note: you don't need to set up any port forwarding.)

That's it. Once set up, you can start your VM. In your VM, the network configuration will look like below and you'll have Internet access too:

[image]

Also in your host machine, you can ssh to your VM:

[image]

Be sure that the SSH server has been installed and up running in the VM.

```
$ ps aux | grep sshd
root 864 0.1 0.5 65512 5392 ? Ss 22:10 0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

If not, install it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Also for your information:

- My VirtualBox version: 5.2.6 r120293 (Qt5.6.2), 2018
- My Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- My host machine: Windows 10

Comment: If you don't have any host-only adapter, you can create one from: `File > Host Network Manager > Create`

Comment: It doesn't reach internet network sadly

Comment: This method is good in that you can also access your VM both from the HOST and from none-HOSTS machines. Awesome!

Answer (score 5):

For Windows host, you can :

1. In virtualbox manager:

   1. select <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> in your virtualbox manager,
   2. then go to network pannel
   3. add a private network

      1. make sure that activate DHCP is NOT selected
2. In network management (windows)

   1. Select the newly created virtualbox host only adapter and the physical network card
   2. Right-Click and select "Make bridge"
3. Enjoy

Answer (score 5):

**SSH Back to Your Home / Office VirtualBox Guest Machine From The INTERNET**

The answers provided by other users here : `How to SSH to a VirtualBox guest externally through a host?`

... helped me to accomplish the task of connecting from out on the internet to my home computer's guest machine. You should be able to connect using computers, tablets, and smart phones (android, IPhone,etc). I add a few more step in case it might be helpful to someone else:

Here is a quick diagram of my setup:

- `Remote device ---> INTERNET --> MODEM --> ROUTER --> HOST MACHINE --> GUEST VM`
- `Remote device (ssh client) ---> PASS THRU DEVICES ---> GUEST VM (ssh server)`
- `Remote device (leave ssh port 3022) ---> INTERNET --> MODEM --> ROUTER (FWD frm:p3022 to:p3022)--> HOST MACHINE (FWD frm:p3022 to:p22) --> GUEST VM (arrive ssh port 22)`

The key for me was to realize that ALL connections was `PASSING-THROUGH` intermediary devices to get from my remote PC to my guest virtual-machine at home --Hence port forwarding!

Notes:
* Need ssh client to request a secure connection and a running ssh server to process the secure connection.

- I will forward the port 3022 as used in the chosen answer from above.
- Enter your IPs where needed (home modem/router, host IP, guest IP,etc.), Names chosen are just examples-use or change.

1.Create ssh tunnel to port 3022 on your modem's IP / router's external IP address.

`ssh client/device possible commands: ssh -p 3022 user-name@home_external_IP`

2.Port forward = we are passing thru the connection from router to host machine

- Also make sure firewall /IPtable rules on router is allowing ports to be forward (open if needed)
- Router's Pfwd SCREEN required entries: AppName:SSH_Fwd, Port_from: 3022, Protocol:both (UDP/TCP), IP_address:hostIP_address, Port_to:3022, everything else can be blank

DD-WRT router software resources / Info:

- [DD-WRT Port_Forwarding](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Port_Forwarding)
- [DD-WRT Static_DHCP](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Static_DHCP)

3.Host Machine Firewall: open port 3022 #so forwarded port can pass thru to guest machine

- Host Machine: Install VirtualBox, guest additions, and guest machine if not done already
- Configure guest machine and then follow the Network section below
- I used VirtualBox GUI to setup guest's network- easier than CLI
- If you want to use other methods refer to : `VirtualBox/manual/ch06.html#natforward`

4.Some suggest using Network Bridge adapter for guest = access to LAN and other machines on your LAN. This also pose an increase security risk, because now your guest machine is now exposed to LAN machines and possibly the INTERNET hackers if firewall not setup properly. So I selected Network adapter attached to NAT for less exposure to bridged security risks.

On the guest machine do the following:

- Guest Machine VirtualBox Network settings: Adapter 1: Attached to NAT
- Guest Machine VirtualBox Port Forwarding Rule: Name:External_SSH, Protocol:TCP, Host Port: 3022, Guest Port 22, Host&guest IPs:leave blank
- click on advance in Network section then click on Port forwarding to enter rules
- Guest Machine Firewall: open port 22 #so ssh connection can enter
- Guest Machine: Make sure that ssh server is installed, configured properly, and running
- LINUX test to see if ssh server running w/command: sudo service ssh status
- Can check netstat to see if connection made to port 22 on the guest machine

Also there are different ssh servers and clients depending on platform using.

- `wikipedia/Secure_Shell`
- `wikipedia/Comparison_of_SSH_servers`
- `wikipedia/Comparison_of_SSH_clients`

For Ubuntu Users:

- `ubuntu community: SSHOpenSSH/Configuring`
- `ubuntu/community: OpenSSH/Keys`

That should be it. If I made a mistake or want to add anything -feel free to do so-- I am still a noob.

Hope this helps someone. Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

You can also initiate a port forward TO your HOST, OR ANY OTHER SERVER, from your Guest.   This is especially useful if your Guest is 'locked' or can't otherwise complete the ModifyVM option (e.g. no permission to VBoxManage).

Three minor requirements are 1) you are/can log into the VirtualBox Guest (via 'console' GUI, another Guest, etc), 2) you have an account on the VirtualBox HOST (or other Server), and 3) SSH and TCP forwarding is not blocked.

Presuming you can meet the 3 requirements, these are the steps:

1. On the Guest, run `netstat -rn` and find the Gateway address to the default route destination 0.0.0.0.  Let's say it's "10.0.2.2".  This 'Gateway' address is (one of) the VirtualBox Host virtual IP(s).
2. On the Guest, run `ssh -R 2222:localhost:22  10.0.2.2` where "10.0.2.2" is the VirtualBox server's IP address -OR- any other server IP you wish to port forward to.
3. On the Host, run `ssh 10.0.2.2 -p2222` where 10.0.2.2 is the default gateway/VBHost virtual IP found in step 1.  If it is NOT the VirtualBox host you are port forwarding to, then the command is `ssh localhost -p2222`

Answer (score 4):

**Follow below steps to login to your ubuntu VM running in virtual box from the host machine using putty (Without port forwarding):**

1. On Virtualbox manager select the vm, click on settings icon. Then go Networks and enable two adaptors as below:

   - Adaptor 1 (For internet access): Attached to -> NAT, Advanced -> Check the cable connected.
   - Adaptor 2: Attached to -> Host only adaptor, Advanced -> Check the cable connected and Promiscuous mode -> Allow all.
2. Start the ubuntu vm.
3. Login to the VM as root.
4. Edit the file '/etc/network/interfaces' as below and save it:

   ```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp

   auto eth1
   iface eth1 inet dhcp
   ```
5. Restart the VM.
6. Login to the VM and run below command to check the IP allocated to eth1:

   ```
   ifconfig
   ```
7. Use this IP to open putty session for the VM.

Answer (score 2):

A good explanation about how to configure port forwarding with NAT is found in the VirtualBox documents:
http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward

Answer (score 2):

**Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**

Configuration with bridged to see the server ip, and connect without "port forwarding"

VirtualBox >  right click in server > settings > Network > enable adapter 2 >  select "bridged" > Promiscuous mode: allow all > Check the cable connected > start server

On ubuntu server, edit `sudo nano /etc/netplan/*init.yaml` file,

**My sample file:**

```
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
        enp0s8:
            addresses: [192.168.0.200/24]
            dhcp4: no
            dhcp6: no
            nameservers:
               addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
    version: 2
```

**Commands that will help you**

```
nano /etc/netplan/file.yaml     # file to specify the rules of network
reboot now                      # restart ubuntu server right now
netplan apply                   # do after edited *.yaml, to apply changes
ifconfig -a                     # show interfaces with ip, netmask, broadcast, etc...
ping google.com                 # to see if there is internet
```

[Configure Static IP Addresses On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server - with NetPlan](https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-static-ip-addresses-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply setting the Network Setting to bridged did the trick for me.

Your IP will change when you do this. However, in my case it didn't change immediately. `ifconfig` returned the same ip. I rebooted the vm and boom, the ip set itself to one start with 192.* and I was immediately allowed ssh access.

Comment: This information I'm guessing is partially or even entirely inaccurate  in some general sense, I have no idea. downvoter didn't bother to say.

Comment: To wit, "for some, it does not work."

Answer (score 0):

On secure networks setting your network to bridge might not work. Administrators could only allow one mac address per port or even worse block the port should the switches detect multiple macs on one port.

The best solution in my opinion is to set up additional network interfaces to handle additional services you would like to run on your machines. So I have a bridge interface to allow for bridging when I take my laptop home and can SSH into it from other devices on my network as well as a host only adapter when I would like to SSH into my VM from my laptop when I am connected to the eduroam wifi network on campus.

Answer (score 0):

Use NAT network adapter and Add port forward. Mention actual host ip.Do not use 127.0.0.1 or localhost.