# ssh: connect to host localhost port 2222: Connection refused

Tags: linux, ssh

I installed `Virtual Box` on my `Linux` OS, in the Virtual Box, I created another `Linux` OS, which has a user called "dvader", I want to SSH from my local Linux OS to the Linux OS on Virtual Box, I used the command below:

```
$ ssh -p 2222 dvader@localhost
```

But I always got the error:

```
ssh: connect to host localhost port 2222: Connection refused
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you expect something to be listening on port `2222`?

Comment: @larsks Because the VirtualBox file is set up to forward port 2222 on my host computer to port 22 on the guest system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuestion: ¿are you using NAT?... SSH listen p22 by default, if you want connection on p2222 edit the ssh_config placed in /etc/ of your VM Guest... find the line (assuming that you are in a *buntu OS family)

```
 39 #   Port 22
```

and change it to

```
 39    Port 2222
```

and there you have it on p2222

BTW, your host could'nt see the guest by name "dvader@localhost", because "localhost" it's indeed your HOST & your GUEST maybe another IP, give more details about your VNetwork config...

Sorry for my english :)

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by `39 #   Port 22`? It is a command?

Comment: 39 is the line number on the ssh_config file... EDIT: now i see your edit... the user dvader is on the admin group ¿?

Comment: Sorry for pointing you to wrong direction, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906441/how-to-ssh-to-a-virtualbox-ubuntu-guest-externally-through-a-windows-host) you can see how to doit in a clean way, other [link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=55766) from de the vbox forum...