# vboxmanage doesn't fully start vm in headless mode

Tags: powershell, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine that I use for development purposes. When I start the VM in headless mode through the VirtualBox UI (v6.1.16), it starts absolutely fine.

However, when I start it with the `vboxmanage` command from PowerShell, using

```bsh
vboxmanage startvm "vm-name" --type headless
```

it doesn't fully start until I open the VirtualBox UI, then it seems to finish the booting process and allow me to connect via SSH.

I have no idea why I have to open the UI to finish off the boot process (it's not a time issue, I've left it for several hours before, but it always completes the boot process fine when I open the UI), is there something in the rather simple `vboxmanage` command I'm missing, or is there likely to be something within the VM setup itself that's preventing a full boot if the UI isn't open?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem ([see here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=111063)) but the proposed solution does not work. From the beginning, the first adapter is NAT and the second one is host-only. However, the headless boot hangs, until I bring the VM windows on the foreground (opening it is not sufficient, it must be brought on the foreground).

Among 14 VM's, only guests running Fedora and Redhat (Rocky Linux) have this problem, not the other VM's, with other distros (Ubuntu, Debian, etc.) All VM's have the same virtual hardware configuration.

Answer (score -1):

This answer fixed this issue for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44369038/12298712

I had my first network interface as Host Adapter and second interface as NAT; I made the first interface NAT and second interface Host Adapter and my VM was able to fully boot with networking working.

If you have static addressing on those network interfaces, you'll need to update `/etc/network/interfaces` to update the interface names.